# use BASH select command to open a file from a file list

Tags: bash, select

I have a file `list.txt` which contains a list of files:

```
file-1.txt
file-2.txt
...
file-n.txt
```

I want to use Bash `select` command to produce a menu so I can open the file that I select.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
select d in list.txt; 
do test -n "$d" && break; 
echo ">>> Invalid Selection"; 
done
open "$d"
```

Comment: Haven't idea what do you want. Please, [mcve]. Clear questions for _one_ exact problem has more chance to better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what ended up working, with all credit to @eush77 and @ilkkachu.

I added an extra part: the list of files is produced by a search program ([ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)).  The code seems to deal fine with spaces in file names.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/bash
list=$(rg --files |grep -i $@)
IFS=$'\n'
select file in $list 
   do test -n "$file" && break; 
exit; 
done
open "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the Bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> select name [ in word ] ; do list ; done
>
> The list of words following in is expanded, generating a list of items. The set of expanded words is printed on the standard error,
>   each preceded by a number. […]

In your example the list of words expands into a single word `list.txt` (and not the list of lines in this file as you want). You need to use command substitution for that:

```
select d in $(<list.txt);   # Change this line
do test -n "$d" && break; 
echo ">>> Invalid Selection"; 
done
open "$d"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ help select
select: select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done    
...
```

Select takes a list of words, just like `for`, not a file name.

You would need to use something like `select d in $(cat list.txt)` to read the choices from the file. But be wary of the usual problems with word-splitting and file name globbing, i.e. set `IFS=$'\n'` if the names in the list can contain spaces, and use `set -f` if they can contain glob characters.